# Save RData to different directory

Tags: r, save

I was using following code some time ago to save my RData files. And it was working perfectly. Today when I tried it is not working. And no errors are reported. Please help me to solve this issue.
I want to save my R files to custom directory that is controlled by file.path.

```
file.path("C:/project/data scrape/")
save(daily.data, file=(file.path("daily.usa.RData")))
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `file=` argument is:

```
file.path("daily.usa.RData")
```

which returns:

```
[1] "daily.usa.RData"
```

You need to save desired filepath as an object:

```
filepath <- file.path("C:/project/data scrape")
```

and then do your save with

```
file = file.path(filepath, "daily.usa.RData")
```

which gives:

```
[1] "C:/project/data scrape/daily.usa.RData"
```